# $scope.myVar updates but not in the view

Tags: angularjs, scope, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router, angular-services

I have a template nested in an other template (menu is the parent template) which share the same controller. My Controller gets the value from a service called counterOperations. Althought $scope.total seems to be updating in console.log the view does not update the value.

Controller

```
.controller('ListController', function ($scope, $http, $state, counterOperations, userService) {

//Some code

 $scope.add = function (index) {
        $scope.total = counterOperations.getTopCounter();
        console.log($scope.total);
    };


})
```

Templates

```
$stateProvider
    .state('app', {
        url: '/app',
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
        controller: "ListController"
    })

$stateProvider
    .state('app.list', {
        url: '/list',
         views: {
            'products': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/product-list.html',
                 controller: "ListController"
            }
        }
    })
```

with ng-click I trigger a function which calls some functions from a service

The view variable for menu

```
 <span>{{total}}</span>
```

I have tried to update the value this way but nothing changes

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $scope.total = counterOperations.getTopCounter();
}, 1000);
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: are you calculating total in app state and want total to be visible in app.list state too?

Comment: The $scope.add func() is triggered after ng-click in app.list. But the {{total}} is in app state. The value is calculated in the counterOperations service and then the $scope.total is updated when the shared controller calls the service function.

Comment: Your app state should watch for changes in your service! Another instance of your controller changed the input namely the one from app.list. This isn't automatically being picked up by the app.state. You can use $scope.watch to see if the value has changed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here your 2 states "*app*" and "*app.list*" have same controller, when you change state from "*app*" to "*app.list*" regardless of same controller controller will reinstantiated which means value in $scope.total variable will lost and will reset in next state.

**Solution** -

*Assign total to $rootScope if you want it in other state too*

```
$scope.add = function (index) {
    $rootScope.total = counterOperations.getTopCounter();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.controller('ListController', function ($scope, $http, $state, counterOperations, userService) {

//Some code
$scope.total = ''; //or $scope.total = 0;

 $scope.add = function (index) {
        $scope.total = counterOperations.getTopCounter();
        console.log($scope.total);
    };


})
```

Check if the above works for you?

Comment: I didn't mention I have the $scope total initialized. The initialized value is 0 and it is shown correctly.